# Using a custom function when order get status 'completed'

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, status, orders

I have an e-commerce website on Wordpress and WooCommerce.

I Would like use some custom function when order is completed.

How can I use my function on order completed status?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_order_status_completed`** hook, this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'custom_wc_order_complete', 10, 2 );
function custom_wc_order_complete( $order_id, $order ) {
    // Here comes your code (doing something), optionally using the $order_id argument
}
```

This function will be triggered when the order status will become "completed" for a specific **`$order_id`** (argument).

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

See this related answers:

- [Change the user role on purchase for specific products when order status is completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41510007/change-the-user-role-on-purchase-for-specific-products-when-order-status-is-comp/41517132#41517132)
- [Get Product Name and Description in WooCommerce email templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41002151/get-product-name-and-description-in-woocommerce-email-templates)
- [WooCommerce: Use PayPal with notify_URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40827900/woocommerce-use-paypal-with-notify-url/40832818#40832818)
- [Insert Values into a custom table once order is placed in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39515723/how-to-insert-values-into-custom-table-after-order-is-placed-in-woocommerce)